# Error while opening pdf using evince

Tags: evince

I have a issue with the evince. The pdf file is not opening in evince and while trying to open the pdf through the terminal by using the command `evince test.pdf`, the following error Is appearing in the terminal-

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please suggest me how to correct this error.

Comment: does it happen for all pdf files or for a specific pdf file?

Comment: It happens for all PDF files

Comment: First check whether it is an issue with your account. Temporarily create a new account and check if the issue also occurs there. If yes, then there is a corruption of your system files. First try reinstalling evince, else you may need to reinstall.

Comment: I already did that but still facing same issue

Comment: I assume you can't open pdfs with the GUI too. I also assume you removed it with `sudo apt remove evince` and then install again with `sudo apt install evince` . You may try to install snap version to see what happens. `sudo snap install evince`

Comment: Worked  for me. Thank